# Database design - Storing keys to all required information vs performing Joins when authorizing access

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

Take the following examples (Only pseudocode) when considering whether a "Company" has access to see information about a "ClientSale". Either I can store the FK references to everything [OPTION B] which could scale to storing a lot of references as the tables grow, or perform joins on Queries [OPTION A] in order to make the access comparisons.

What are the benefits and pitfalls of each approach? Is there an even better option?

OPTION A

```
CREATE TABLE Company (
  Id,
  ...
)

CREATE TABLE Client (
  Id,
  CompanyId FK
)

CREATE TABLE ClientSale (
  Id,
  ClientId FK
)
```

OPTION B

```
CREATE TABLE Company (
  Id,
  ...
)

CREATE TABLE Client (
  Id,
  CompanyId FK
)

CREATE TABLE ClientSale (
  Id,
  CompanyId FK,
  ClientId FK
)
```

EDIT

Should I break it down into more tables [Company_Client & ClientSale_Client & Company_ClientSale] ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBMS's expect your FKs will form a multi-layer hierarchy, as you show for option A. So they're optimised for `JOIN` queries across FKs.

The disadvantage of repeating FKs in grand-child tables per your option B is you are now duplicating information, making extra work when updating, and giving risk of anomalies: your code might `UPDATE Client SET CompanyId = ...` but forget to `UPDATE ClientSale WHERE ClientId = ... SET CompanyId = ...`. Also a co-ordinated `UPDATE` like that will need `COMMMIT` control to avoid your tables getting out of step.